# How to install older version of lutris?

Tags: lutris

I am using Ubuntu 18.04. These are the commands I typed to install lutris.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:lutris-team/lutris
sudo apt update
sudo apt install lutris
```

It said `lutris is already the newest version (0.5.10~ubuntu18.04.1)`.

How do I install version 0.5.9.1 instead?

Comment: *How do I install version 0.5.9.1 instead?* You don't because for all supported releases the PPA provides 5.10. 5.9 was available to the now unsupported 21.04.

Comment: Did you ever found a solution? Would also love to install 5.9.1. again, as it worked better for me

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for an older version too, as the one I have, 0.5.10, seems to fail to run a certain setup file.

I hope this may help you:
https://github.com/lutris/lutris/releases/tag/v0.5.9.1

You can get it through the deb file or build from source. I am using it on Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).